# How to detect leaks of UIKit objects?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

```
- (void)btnInboxPressed
{
    for (int j = 0; j < 100000; j++) {
        [[UIButton alloc] init];
    }
}
```

Why would this not show up as a memory leak in Instruments?  If I alloc NSMutableString in the same fashion, Instruments flags a memory leak.

[image]

Comment: Isn't it simply because setLeftBarButtonItem method releases the old object in your code? Am I missing something?

Comment: My code should read    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Quotes" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(btnInboxPressed)] autorelease];  navigationItem retains the button that I alloc'd, but I am responsible to release my own alloc.

Answer (score 3):

It may be because there is something somewhere that is still pointing to each button;  still has a reachable reference to each button instance.

A "leak" is an object (or allocation) for which there is no way the program can every refer to it again. The address of said object no longer appears anywhere in the program.

There are, however, a multitude of ways you can accrete memory without it being counted as a leak.

Write-only caches are a classic failure pattern.   So are registries where every instance is registered with some central scrutinizer.   The central scrutinizer still has a valid reference -- thus not a leak -- even though you don't need the object again.

You are doing exactly what you should;  "Holy cow! Why does instruments show that I have 10,000 UIButtons!?!?!?  If I figure that out and make 'em go away, my memory use will drop significantly!!"

---

In this specific case, it might be that the autorelease pool still has a reference to the object.  It might be that allocation and initialization of a UIButton causes it to be retain/autoreleased somewhere along the way.

No way to know without knowing where in the event loop that screenshot was grabbed.

Comment: The screenshot was grabbed after the event loop finished. I could press the button again and get another 100K button to show in Instruments. That "something somewhere still pointing to each button" is not in my code...some global list of UI objects in UIKit?  Like I said, a single `[[NSMutableString alloc] init];` will trigger a detected leak.  The leak detection of Instruments just doesn't seem very useful if it does not work on UI objects.

Comment: If you turn on "track retain/release events" or whatever it is called, you could look at the retain/release events for any given UIButton and see what is still retaining it (beyond your code).  The frameworks are free to make wonky assumptions regarding retain counts.

Comment: is track retain/release events a setting in Instruments?

Comment: Also, I found this article this is helpful in tracking down leaks: "When is a leak not a leak" [link](http://www.friday.com/bbum/2010/10/17/when-is-a-leak-not-a-leak-using-heapshot-analysis-to-find-undesirable-memory-growth/)

Comment: Good -- glad that article is helpful!  Yes --- if you click the little (i) button on the Allocations instrument, there is a "track retain/release" check box (can't remember what it is called right now).